# OOP Javascript use Promise and problems with "this"

Tags: javascript, oop, promise, prototype

When designing OOP ES 5-6, where I combine prototypes with ES 6 functions. Everything is running in ElectronJS, I do not want a new version that fully supports ES 7 too, so for example the definition of import {trida} from "./cesta" must be solved require ('./ path'). My problem, but it's in Promise.

If I want to program object, I want every object to do what it has and pass the result to the main branch of the program, which contains the column of the whole procedure - object list - Content. If fun enter setTimeout (), you need to use the Promise here, which waits until the function is executed and continues to call another object.

```js
let importing = function(){
 this.name = "boot";
}

importing.prototype.start = function(resolve){
    this.resolve = resolve;
    setTimeout(this.test.bind(this),1000);
 console.log('start -------->');
}

importing.prototype.test = function(){
    this.resolve('Test');
 console.log('Test -------->');
}


importing.prototype.end = function(resolve){ 
 console.log('end -------->');
    this.resolve = resolve;
    this.resolve('end');
}

let geko;
let scan = new importing();
Promise.resolve(geko)
 .then((geko) => new Promise(scan.start.bind(scan)))
 .then((geko) => new Promise(scan.end.bind(scan)))
 .catch(geko => {
     console.log('Error message: ',geko)
 })
```

Here is the problem, I do not want the features to nest in the prototype functions, I want to call every object, nicely in order, clearly. Like any book, it has its Chapter Content, and then the chapters itself and I want to have a quick entry into what I have programmed and did not look at how much a mouse was taken after a week. But for this operation, besides Promise, I also have to use the bind () function because:

```js
importing.prototype.start = function(){
// here this acts as a window object not as importing
// why I have this object called scan.start.bind (scan)
// and here again in setTimeout i have to bind (this) to get it in this.test
// could access this importing - scan object
  setTimeout(this.test.bind(this),300);
}
```

You would find a better way??

Comment: Uh, this is not how you would use promises at all.

Comment: So this example works and the promise I need, but I still think it is scabbard. Or do you have a better idea? Because according to this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise I cut it to a minimum of characters.

Comment: I don't think your example code works. Maybe post your actual full code.

Comment: ok, so I modified it so you let it go.ok, so I modified it so you let it go. See below

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting the update as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass methods as the argument to the `new Promise` constructor. If the method is asynchronous, it should return a promise by itself; if it's not asynchronous then you shouldn't be using any promises.

```
function importing(){
    this.name = "boot";
}

importing.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log('start -------->');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000); // put the native async call in here, and nothing else!
    }).then(() =>
        this.test()
    );
};

importing.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log('Test -------->');
    return 'Test';
};

importing.prototype.end = function() { 
    console.log('end -------->');
    return 'end';
}

const scan = new importing();
scan.start().then(() => scan.end()).catch(geko => {
    console.log('Error message: ',geko)
});
```

Comment: I've just tried a performance test for your solution and mine, and it looks like my solution is a bit faster. Anyway, thank you very much for your feedback. I appreciate it.
Yours sincerely, Dalibor

Comment: @DaliborAdamec I doubt so. All the time is spent in the 1s timeout, the rest is negligible.

Comment: Yes you are right, there is very little, I have simplified it so I did not have to add this.result to each object.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole project was created as follows:

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    }).then(() =>
        this.test()
    );
```

I would not have much to do with the classic JS procedure, ie the nesting of functions in the functions. That's what I want to avoid. I want content, an outline, when I look at it for a year and I'm going to solve the bugs, I'll know where to start and where the mistakes are going.

```js
let importing = function(){
 this.name = "boot";
}

importing.prototype.start = function(resolve){
 console.log('Start');
    this.resolve = resolve;
    setTimeout(this.test.bind(this),1000);
}

importing.prototype.test = function(){
 console.log('Test');
    this.resolve('Test');
}

importing.prototype.end = function(resolve){
 console.log('End');
    resolve('end');
}

let scan = new importing();
let promise = function(arg){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{ // The same: new Promise(scan[arg].bind(scan))
  return scan[arg].bind(scan)(resolve)
 });
}

// so I would imagine chaining. Few braces, simply
// In each called object, if possible, the minimum promissory note

Promise.resolve()
 .then(geko => promise('start'))
 .then(geko => promise('end'))
 .catch(geko => {
     console.log('Error message: ',geko)
 })
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*the classic JS procedure, ie the nesting of functions in the functions*". And why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: Because, as if the content of the book determines a quick overview of what it is, I also want to have a quick entry into my code because, I am a fullstack developer and unfortunately I forget a lot when working with Angleter 2+ or with NodeJs and ElectroneJS. I'm working on an autonomous application that has to constantly adapt, very hard to maintain.